# How to create CSV and PDF using array as a data source in c#

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, csv

I have a class

```
public class Data
    {
        public string name{ get; set; }
        public int age { get; set; } 
    }
```

And I have a method which accept array of data, I need to generate csv and pdf from the upcoming data.

```
 public void ExportToCSV(Data[] data)
    {
        // write code to generate csv
    }


 public void ExportToPdf(Data[] data)
    {
        // write code to generate pdf
    }
```

Please suggest.

I generated Excel like this, and wondering to have similar code which generate csv and pdf. What change will be needed?

```
   public void ExportToExcel(Data[] data)
        {

           var grid = new GridView();
            grid.DataSource = data;
            grid.DataBind();

            Response.ClearContent();

            Response.AddHeader("Content-type", "application/vnd.ms-excel");

            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=export.xls");

            Response.ContentType = "application/excel";

            var swr = new StringWriter();

            var tw = new HtmlTextWriter(swr);

            grid.RenderControl(tw);

            Response.Write(swr.ToString());

            Response.Flush();

            Response.End();
            tw.Close();

            swr.Close();
        }
```

Comment: What your CSV should look like? Can you give us an example?

Comment: What are your attempts so far? At this point you have shown no code yet.

Comment: The properties name should be in header and their value right below them Like this  http://www.trirand.net/examples/grid/exporting/csv/default.aspx

Comment: I did not attempt anything yet, because I don't know how can I generate those two different file using array?

Comment: FileHelpers will be a great tool for the CSV stuff, not 100% on the PDF of course, but there are a number or reporting style tools that you might be able to use?

Comment: The data which I am sending from the client look like this {'data':[{"name":"abc","age":"4"},{"name":"xyz","age":"5"}]}

Comment: I need a little simple code which process the upcoming data and generate those file. Can you please make one for me?

Comment: @user2866746: we don't do code requests. What we do is provide advise and help when you're stuck with a concrete problem.

Comment: @user2866746, that's not CSV. That's JSON that you've shown us in your comments.

Answer (score 1):

Use LINQ:

```
string csv = data.ToLidt()
             .Select(i => string.Format("{0}, {1}", i.name, i.age.ToString())
             .Aggregate((a, b) => string.Format("{0}\r\n{1}"));
```

Update:

Well, technically, your Excel generation code is not creating Excel. You're just using `GridView` render control class, which I doubt to create Excel at all.

But to create PDF and any other document, your path is just the same:

1. Creating the file on the server using some third-party libraries
2. Sometimes that file needs to be saved temporarily, which in that case you can look [here](http://nefcanto.com/getting-temporary-folder-for-the-current-user-in-csharp).
3. You should set the correct MIME Type on the response, so that browser knows what it has to do with the content.
4. You should set `Content-Disposition` header, so that browser downloads the file, instead of opening it.
5. And you at last write the file to the response stream as a binary array.

Comment: I would like to ask you the same question how can I send file to the browser to download?

Comment: Then ask, we're here to help :)

Comment: I edit my post, please check

Answer (score 1):

try

```
 using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\Test\yourFile.csv"))
 {
   file.WriteLine("name,age");
   foreach(var item in data)
   {
      file.WriteLine(String.Format("{0},{1}", item.name, item.age));
   }
 }
```

Comment: After this code run, how the browser will know it will need to open this file?

Comment: I thinnk that you are confusing JSON with CSV

Comment: Don't worry about json, I will convert it later into array on the server. I need to know how can I send the file to the browser